# how to get json response in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, json, jsp

I am making an ajax POST request in my project which will check the database value and returns me some response.When i make a request it does not returns me the text that i written.Am i missing something ? 
My expected result should be success if it matches the condition or else Hello.
Thanks in advance !
My Script

```
 var mydata = $("#form").serialize()+"&" + $.param(data);
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "loginCheck.jsp",
          dataType : "json",
          data: mydata,
          error:function (res){ 
               console.log(res);
                            },
          success: function(response){
               console.log("response", response);
                            }
           });
```

My loginCheck.jsp

```
  <%@page import="com.google.gson.Gson"%>
  <%@page import="com.admin.DBConnec"%>
  <%
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String username = request.getParameter("uname").trim();
     String password= request.getParameter("upass").trim();
     try{
          DBConnec db =new DBConnec();
          db.stmt=db.con.prepareStatement("SELECT username, AES_DECRYPT(userpass, 'sumn2u') from user where username='"+username+"'");
          db.Rs=db.stmt.executeQuery(); 
            while(db.Rs.next()){ 

      String user=(db.Rs.getString(1));
      String pass=(db.Rs.getString(2));
       session.setAttribute("username", user);

       if(user.equals(username) && pass.equals(password)){
            out.println("success");

        }else {    
            response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson("Hello"));
        } 
        }

       }catch (Exception ex){
           System.out.println("Exception Occured : "+ ex);
       }     

%>
```

And what i got in my console is 
[image]

Its adding the spaces what would i have to do to remove space so that i could get success only or may be in JSON format.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the network tab to make sure the request headers look okay?

Comment: What did you expect to see in your console? It looks like a successful call to me. (It has a status of "200, OK")

Comment: yes its returning  status of 200

Comment: I see that. (From your console output.) But why is that wrong?

Comment: i was expecting something like if the username and password matches it should return the matching condition response i.e success

Comment: Ok. That should go in your question. "Expected result" is always needed, so we can know what you want your code to do.

Comment: Also, it wouldn't hurt to type out an object like the one that should be returned by the server. (i.e., this is what I got <insert here>; this is what I expected <insert here>)

Comment: @jpaugh ok so what should i do to return  the response message it showing me  another responseText

Comment: Could you post what the network tab tells you about the AJAX response too?

Comment: I think i found some error @jpaugh its like i get the success its adding spaces so was seeing that response

Comment: If that doesn't work, try reducing to a smaller piece of code that still fails. Then, figure out how to fix that. The smaller your failing case is, the easier it is to understand.

Comment: On new tab open loginCheck.jsp and please post data which you get there. Add   `out.println("User pass match ");` if user pass is correct.

Comment: i figure it out with XMLHttpRequest() and the response i get  i truncate the additional spaces now its working fine thank you for all .